# Cloudera Post deployment config updates

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

In cloudera is there a way to update list of configurations at a time using CM-API or CURL?

Currently I am updating one by one one using below CM API.

```
      services_api_instance.update_service_config()
```

How can we update all configurations stored in json/config file at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The CM API endpoint you're looking for is `PUT /cm/deployment`.  From the [CM API documentation](http://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v18/path__cm_deployment.html):

> Apply the supplied deployment description to the system. This will create the clusters, services, hosts and other objects specified in the argument. This call does not allow for any merge conflicts. If an entity already exists in the system, this call will fail. You can request, however, that all entities in the system are deleted before instantiating the new ones.

This basically allows you to configure all your services with one call rather than doing them one at a time.

If you are using services that require a database (Hive, Hue, Oozie ...) then make sure you set them up **before** you call the API.  It expects all the parameters you pass in to work so external dependencies must be resolved first.